# Calling public method of jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, methods, call, public

I´ve tried a jQuery Plugin Boilerplate from this Site : [jQuery_boilerplate](http://wiki.shopware.de/Boilerplate-jQuery-Plugins_detail_1068.html), but i can´t call the public Method fooBar.
My implemantion looks like:

```
/**
 * jQuery lightweight plugin boilerplate
 * Original author: @ajpiano
 * Further changes, English comments: @addyosmani
 * More further changes, German translation: @klarstil
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 */
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    "use strict";

    var pluginName = 'defaultPluginName',
        defaults = {
            propertyName: "value"
        };    

    var privateMethod = function() {
    };

    function Plugin( element, options ) {

        this.element = element;
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();

    }

    Plugin.prototype.init = function () {
    };

    Plugin.prototype.fooBar = function(someValue) {
        var fooBarModifier = 3;

        function privateFooBar(someValue) {
            return someValue * fooBarModifier;
        }

        someValue = privateFooBar(someValue);
        return someValue;
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, 
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    }
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

For Example i use the Plugin like this:

```
$('#wrapper').defaultPluginName();
```

and i try to call the method like this:

```
$('#wrapper').fooBar();
```

But my Console gives me bck an this Error:

> TypeError: $(...).fooBar is not a function $('#wrapper').fooBar();

How can I call a Method on this Selection?

Comment: it is because `$('#wrapper').` does not return an instance of `Plugin`, it returns a jQuery wrapper for the matched set of dom elements which does not have the `fooBar` method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because `$('#wrapper')` does not return an instance of the plugin, it returns a jQuery wrapper for the matched set of DOM elements which does not have the `fooBar` method.

If you want to call the plugin's public method, try:

```
$('#wrapper').data('plugin_defaultPluginName').fooBar();
```

The plugin instance is stored as data to the element with name `'plugin_' + pluginName`, so:

1. `$('#wrapper').data('plugin_defaultPluginName')` will return the instance of plugin named `defaultPluginName`
2. `.fooBar();` calls the method `fooBar` within the plugin instance

Comment: How to modify the code if I want still use  **$('#wrapper').fooBar();** to call the method